# Convert image to black/white contours

Tags: gimp, image-processing

Is there any tool to convert a colour picture to a black and white picture with just contours?

Comment: You can do it in an image editor like GIMP, if GIMP is OK with you.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it? I’ve not used gimp much and cant draw.

Comment: what do you mean by just contours? Do you have an example?

Comment: Like the borders between two colours. Like in ”colouring books”. At some level I guess you must treat different RGB values as the same colour to avoid having too many black lines

Comment: cell-shading it is called ;)  Example tutorial: https://www.deviantart.com/wastelander7/art/Quick-And-Dirty-Cell-Shading-In-Gimp-383945156 It is a manual task though afair

Comment: GIMP has Edge-Detect Filters in the Filter menu. Depending on the image, you may want to do a combination of color processing and kernel convolution. Alternatively, you could use the "fuzzy select tool" or the "scissors select tool", both of which will create a selection based on edge detection, which you can then transform to a path and stroke it. Or manually create a path in the first place. Or you can try `Colors>Threshold...`. But that really depends on the image. AFAIK there is no one-click-solution for every possible image.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, inkscape's [bitmap tracing](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tutorials/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html) may be worth a try.

Comment: Exemple picture perhaps?